# How to put an object's items into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have an object that has some other objects inside. I want to put all of these inside objects into an array.

I tried for loop and in each iteration I would push those objects into an array. The problem is that when I log the array, after the for loop finished ,it would have only the last inserted object. I assume every new iteration would set a new array and in process kinda the previous array would be erased.

Right now I can't provide any code. But soon I put everything in a repo and shared here.

Thanks

Comment: At least provide an input and output example

Comment: *"Right now I can't provide any code. But soon I put everything in a repo and shared here."*. Please only provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not [on an external site/repo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) but inside your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this will help

```js
let objectA = {a: 'value A'}
let objectB = {b: 'value B'}
let objectC = {c: 'value C'}

let obj = {objectA, objectB, objectC}

let output = [];

for (let value of Object.values(obj)) {
  // Filter here if needed
  output.push(value);
}

console.warn(output)
```

Try to create array outside of the loop to prevent your case

`Object.values` will return an array containing object's value of each key. If you want both key and value, you can use `Object.entries` instead

Comment: Is it need to use `for`?.  I think `Object.values(obj)` is enough.

Comment: What is the return value of `Object.values(obj)`? Where does the value of `output` differ when assigned like ... `const output = Object.values(obj)` ... and the above iterating solution?

Comment: this one work perfect. thanks bro

Comment: Yes, `Object.values(obj)` alone is OK. But what if `obj` has string or number value. You still need to use `for` to filter them out. And like I've stated `Object.values` will return an array containing object's value of each key

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
const obj = {
  objectA: { a: "898738" },
  objectB: { b: "123123" },
  objectC: { c: "23122321" },
};
const output = Object.values(obj);

console.log({ output });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```